# How do you check your phone with Sinch.com android?

Tags: android, sinch

I need to check your phone with Sinch.com android.

https://www.sinch.com/products/verification/voice-verification/

etc
- phone:+1-54554-54455-545
- text: press number 2

I need to replicate this text and get back what number the user clicked or that he finished the conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you change the message in https://www.sinch.com/docs/verification/rest/#verificationcallbackapi

There you set the number to press also, we will verify thats its correct and then send a another callback with the result.

https://www.sinch.com/docs/verification/rest/#VerificationResultEvent

At the same time when you use our sdk we will send a signal to the handset so it can continue

Comment: Link: https://api.sinch.com/verification/v1/verifications  . I use post with my request body: 

{"event":"VerificationRequestEvent","method":"callout","identity":{"type":"number","endpoint":"+1-54554-54455-545"},"action":"allow","callout":{"locale":"en-US","ttsMenu":"press number 2","pin":"2"}}

Why tts with default text?
How get callback?

Comment: You configure where you want to the callbacks to be posted in the dashboard, you dont post to that, you reply to the incoming request
https://sinch.com/dashboard

Comment: I need send request with dynamically generated string (etc. Mr. Anderson or Ms. Smith, please press 1 or 2 or 3).
When I send request body: 
 
Link: api.sinch.com/verification/v1/verifications . I use post with my request body: {"event":"VerificationRequestEvent","method":"callout","identity":{"type":"numbe‌​r","endpoint":"+1-54554-54455-545"}} - Sinch-server calls always with default text. How make what do I need (calls with dynamically generated text) ?

Comment: or request body: { "identity": { "type": "number", "endpoint": "+1-54554-54455-545" }, "reference": "Hello Mike, press 3", "method": "callout", "metadata": { "os": "rest", "platform": "N/A" } } 

How make what do I need (calls with dynamically generated text) ?

Comment: No, you are confusing the mehtods, which is of course our fault. But you dont post with that data for a callout, https://www.sinch.com/docs/verification/rest#VerificationRequest is where you call, and there you cant set the message.
In the Callback however you can, that a response to the to the verificaitonREquestEvent that Sinch back end will post to your backend
https://www.sinch.com/docs/verification/rest#verificationcallbackapi

Comment: Thanks for the consultation.